# cx_Freeze "error in the main script" window not opening

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface

Ok, so I am creating an exe for my calculator. After I had launched the application once the build was created, it created an error window but for some reason, the window won't open. I've tried using alt - tab to switch but the window still won't open entirely which is preventing me from pinpointing the issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwaR2.png)

The small window at the bottom right is the window with the error of the application. However, it won't open and I was hoping there is a solution as to why it won't open?

Comment: There's a lot of red text in the bottom right of the screenshot. Isn't it the error message from the script?

Comment: ignore that thats for the fact that i was suppose to use cmd to build the setup.py file.

Answer (score 0):

If your application does not work there is an error.

The setup script seems OK but I am dubious about `base = none followed by base = win32gui` and `win64gui`.

Try replacing it with:

```
if(sys.platform == 'win32'):
    base = 'WIN32GUI'
else:
    base = None
```

Also you do not mention if errors appear (or at least you cannot see them) try running the application with command prompt.

This is probably the best way of finding out what the problem is.  From this you should be able to work out what's going wrong.

EDIT:

I have found out `Win64GUI` does not exist.  It's `Win32GUI` or `None`

Comment: Ok so idk if its visible in the code but Im using kivy so I decided to use PyInstaller instead which worked for me.

Comment: @user199845 PyInstaller is probably better if you can since it can generate single file outputs (or so I heard) unlike Cx_Freeze.